# Azure app registration do not show up after creation

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to add a new application to my azure AD to use for my Xamarin forms mobile app, but when I select Native app and finish the creation it does not show up under App Registrations but it does show up under enterprise applications but with a subset of functionality it seems, for example I cannot add users to the application and I cannot add reply to URLS etc, What could cause this behaviour?

Comment: If its under Enterprise Applications, then it has a service principal, which has to be created from an Application. It is there. Make sure you select All Apps, and you can also filter the list by name.

Comment: DOH it was filtered on My Apps, note to self stop coding after 30 hours, make this an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the new filter to **All Apps** instead of **My Apps**.

Then it will show all Applications in the tenant.